# How to phrase subsetting to choose a selection from different column

Tags: r, expression, subset

I have a large data frame that I want to subset automatically based on selected variables from different columns (one at a time).

For example, there are 4 columns in a data frame `df` I want to subset rows containing 'a' in 'cola', next time rows containing 'b' in 'cola', rows containing 'c' in 'cola', rows containing 'a' in 'colb', etc. So,

```
df <- data.frame(cola=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b'),
                 colb=sample(c('a', 'b', 'c'), 20, replace=TRUE),
                 colc=sample(20), key=c('a', 'b'))
select1 <- colnames(df)[1:2] #column names to choose from for subsetting
i <- 1L #choose first name of column from vector 'cola'
select2 <- unique(df[[select1[i]]]) #variables in column 'cola' to choose from for subsetting
j <- 1L #choose first name of variable from vector
sdf <- subset(df, select1[i] == select2[j]) #subset rows containing 'a' from column 'cola'
```

and this returns an error.
I want to get a subset as if I used:

```
sdf <- subset(df, cola == "a") #select1[1] == select2[1]
sdf <- subset(df, cola == "b") #select1[1] == select2[2]
sdf <- subset(df, cola == "c") #select1[1] == select2[3]
sdf <- subset(df, colb == "a") #select1[2] == select2[1]
```

etc. ...
Can anyone help me to phrase the logical expression for subsetting based on created vectors to ba able to choose from?

Comment: how do you want the resulting subsets to be arranged?

Comment: I'm going to use it in a loop using for()

Comment: sdf <- df[df[select1[1]] == select2[1], ] does what I want, but it will work for data frames only (I believe).

Answer (score 1):

`split()` will split a dataset by a factor.  So if you apply `split` over the columns that you want to split on you will make a list of lists of the subsets that you want.

Then using `unlist(recursive=FALSE)` will turn this into a single list of subsets that you can loop or apply over.

```
mySubsets <- lapply(names(df)[1:2] , function(name) split(df, df[[name]])) |> 
   unlist(recursive = FALSE)


> mySubsets

$a
   cola colb colc key
1     a    c   16   a
4     a    a   19   b
7     a    b   14   a
10    a    a   11   b
13    a    c    5   a
16    a    c   12   b
19    a    a   18   a

$b
   cola colb colc key
2     b    b    9   b
5     b    c   13   a
8     b    a    7   b
11    b    c    2   a
14    b    b   20   b
17    b    c   15   a
20    b    b    3   b

$c
   cola colb colc key
3     c    a    4   a
6     c    c   10   b
9     c    c    1   a
12    c    c    6   b
15    c    c   17   a
18    c    c    8   b

$a
   cola colb colc key
3     c    a    4   a
4     a    a   19   b
8     b    a    7   b
10    a    a   11   b
19    a    a   18   a

$b
   cola colb colc key
2     b    b    9   b
7     a    b   14   a
14    b    b   20   b
20    b    b    3   b

$c
   cola colb colc key
1     a    c   16   a
5     b    c   13   a
6     c    c   10   b
9     c    c    1   a
11    b    c    2   a
12    c    c    6   b
13    a    c    5   a
15    c    c   17   a
16    a    c   12   b
17    b    c   15   a
18    c    c    8   b
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! However, I look for a basic solution (if it exists)  as I have a ?apply functions-disability. ;( I can use it on a copy-paste basis, but can't create one by myself.

Comment: If you're going to use R seriously then practice using the apply functions.  `lapply` is easy, it just applies the function in its second argument to every element of the first, and returns the results as a list.  Eg try `lapply(df, class)` or `lapply(names(df), toupper)` or something like that.  I don't know how I would solve this problem without `lapply`!

Comment: I seriously use the basic control-flow constructs like `for(var in seq) expr`. I grew up on BASIC. I am aware that `apply` functions are superior. Believe me, I do my best to master them.